# GO package "os" file file_windows.go

Tags: golang

В файле file_windows.go в пакете "os" есть такой код:

```
type File struct {
    *file
}

type file struct {
    fd      syscall.Handle
    name    string
    dirinfo *dirInfo   
    l       sync.Mutex 
    isConsole bool
    lastbits  []byte 
    readbuf   []rune 
}
```

Вопросы по первому struct File:

1. Зачем так написан данный структ? (я в плане был бы просто второй структ и все, зачем первый тут?)
2. Что хранит в себе данный структ? В нем же нету ни какого поля, пример:

   ```
   f *file // а там написано просто *file
   ```
3. Как обратится к какому-то полю через файл?

   ```
   var x File
   fmt.Println(x.name) // ошибка
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File` содержит в себе указатель на структуру `file`.
Сама структура `file` неэкспортируема (начинается с маленькой буквы, в отличие от `File`), как и поля структуры.

В самих исходниках написано, что это сделано для того, чтобы к полям структуры наверняка нельзя было обратиться напрямую. Т.к. `file` представляет собой открытый файловый дескриптор, перезапись его полей напрямую может привести к неожиданным последствиям.

Чтобы получить доступ, например, к имени файла есть функция `.Name()`.

Также добавлю, что "под капотом" функции из `os` для изменения каких-либо атрибутов файла (например, изменение прав через `.Chmod()`) делается через системные вызовы (`package syscall`).